# How to make status update when only value site assembly exist on temp table location based on Revision Id?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

I work on a SQL Server 2012 query and I face an issue : I can't update status when at least one assembly site record on temp table `#rev` matches temp table `#location` based on Revision Id .

Expected result is :

```
Revision Id   Status    
------------------------
1900          Found
2000          Not Found
5000          Found
```

As an example: Revision Id 1900 status will be `Found` because Revision Id 1900 in temp table `#rev` is equal to `LocRevisionId` in temp table `#location` and assembly site in temp table `#rev` is equal to `locAssemblySiteId` in temp table `#location` at least once.

AND

Revision Id 2000 status will be `Not Found` because Revision Id 2000 in `#rev` is equal to `LocRevisionId` in `#location` and Assembly Site in `#rev` is not equal to `locAssemblySiteId` in `#location` at least once.

```
create table #rev
(
    RevisionId int,
    AssemblySiteId int,
    Status nvarchar(200)
)

insert into #rev (RevisionId, AssemblySiteId)
values (1900, 200), (2000, 300), (5000, 800)

create table #location
(
    locRevisionId int,
    locAssemblySiteId int
)

insert into #location (locRevisionId, locAssemblySiteId)
values (1900, 200), (1900, 150),
       (2000, 290), (2000, 310),
       (5000, 800), (5000, 820)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` and a `case` expression:

```
update #rev
set status = case 
    when exists (
        select 1
        from #location l
        where 
            l.locRevisionId = #rev.RevisionId 
            and l.locAssemblySiteId = #rev.AssemblySiteId
    )
    then 'Found'
    else 'Not Found'
end;
```

If there is always at most one row in the location table per revision, then a `left join` is also a possible option:

```
update r
set r.status = case when l.locRevisionId is null then 'Not Found' else 'Found' end
from #rev r
left join #location l 
    on l.locRevisionId = r.RevisionId 
    and l.locAssemblySiteId = r.AssemblySiteId
)
```